# OCMock Argument Match on Double Pointer

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

For a selector like this:

```
-(void) callFoo:(NSError**)error;
```

How can I get an expectation like the below to work? ARC is not liking this kind of expectation, and I don't want to disable ARC for the entire unit test file!

```
[[mockObject expect] callFoo:[OCMArg anyPointer]];
```

Comment: when you say "ARC is not liking...", what kind of error or compiler warning are you seeing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Often times, there's no other way than to write a wrapper selector that OCMock likes when OCMock has a problem with a certain selector. Ugly hack, but it gets around it, let's you use ARC, and takes less than a minute to setup.

I find myself using it all the time with OCMock, unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrapper selector" in this context?

Comment: I add a function that wraps the call and who's arguments are ones that can be easily mocked as opposed to the function being wrapped...

Answer (score 21):

`anyPointer` returns void *, but under ARC, [double pointers to Objective-C objects are implicitly qualified with __autoreleasing](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters).

Try changing it to:

```
[[mockObject expect] callFoo:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)[OCMArg anyPointer]];
```

Comment: there's also `[OCMArg anyObjectRef]`